# picking balls randomly -- perceived discrepancy between solution methods

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came across this problem:

> A drawer contains 3 white balls and 6 black balls. Two balls are drawn
>   out of the box at random. What is the probability that they both are
>   white?

, which I tried solving reasoning as follows:

1. the probability of choosing a white ball on the first try is 1/3.
2. the probability of choosing a white ball on the second try is 2/9 (assuming the first wasn't replaced)
3. multiplying these two gives **2/27**, which is what I took for the answer.

However, the official answer was the following:

> There are $\binom{9}{2} = 36$ combinations of two balls that can be
>   drawn. There are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ combinations of two white balls
>   that can be drawn. So the probability that two balls pulled out are
>   both white is $\dfrac{3}{36} = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{12}}$

Where did I go wrong in my reasoning with this problem?

Comment: After picking the first ball, there are only 8 balls in the bag and hence the second probability is 2/8.

Comment: @Muralidharan  Thanks, can't believe I missed that.  Just posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer just occurred to me.

My reasoning in step 2 was false.

After the first ball has been chosen, there are 8 in total.

So it should be 2/8 * 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no replacement and $W_i$ denote the probability that the $i$-th ball drawn is white then:$$P(W_1\cap W_2)=P(W_1)P(W_2\mid W_1)=\frac39\frac28$$